# RMSE calculation in un-logged space using cross validation when target is logged

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, prediction, cross-validation

I am new to python and facing difficulty to calculate RMSE through cross validation when target has been logged.

I have define the RMSE function in below manner (when target is not logged):

```
def rmse_cv(model):
rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, X_train_s, Y_train,  scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv = 5))
return(rmse)

model_ridge = Ridge()
alphas = [0.005, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 5, 10, 15]
cv_ridge = [rmse_cv(Ridge(alpha = alpha)).mean() for alpha in alphas]
print(cv_ridge)
```

Now, I want to replace the Y_train with logged target Y_log_train and calculate the RMSE in un-logged space. I am not sure how to do this while doing cross validation.

If I have to run the model for one alpha value and get the RMSE on training data, I would follow below steps:

```
model_ridge = Ridge(alpha =10).fit(X_train_s, Y_log_train)
y_pred_log_r = model_ridge.predict(X_train_s)
y_pred_r = np.exp(y_pred_log_r)

RMSE_ridge_train =np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_train, y_pred_r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would simply have the RMSE of your log values. You can't say that the residual of the log value versus your observed value is the log of the residual of the true value and your observed value.

If you log transform your variables, the RMSE is just the RMSE of your transformed variables.

edit: found this to clarify a little more https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56658/how-do-you-interpret-rmsle-root-mean-squared-logarithmic-error

Comment: I am wondering if I have to compare set of models based on RMSE on logged and un-logged target, how would I do that? Thanks for your response though!

Comment: It's the same calculation. One uses `y1 = x`, the other uses `y2 = z` where `z = log(x)`. You would then calculate RMSE for both `y1` and `y2` and compare.

Comment: I did that but the values are not comparable. They are very different. In fact, i tried to see if the RMSE value  are same for alpha = 10 using two approaches, mentioned in my question but they are different. That's the reason I am looking for right suggestion.

Comment: Right because RMSE has the units of the variable you're measuring the error in. If I had an error of $5 my RMSE would be in terms of dollars, if i had an error of 10 lbs, my RMSE would be in terms of lbs 

So because you're new units are log(old units), your RMSE will be in terms of your new units..